# one2many in kanban nothing is displayed

Tags: xml, odoo, kanban, one2many

I am using Odoo 12. I don't have access to Odoo's Python part, only the Odoo developer mode. I installed the `web_one2many_kanban` module but apart from the images and the id of the lines of my `one2many`, I can not display the rest of the data.

My code:

```
<t t-name="kanban-box">
  <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_card  {{ record.x_bom_line_ids.raw_value }}">
    <t t-if="record.x_bom_line_ids.raw_value">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <strong>
            <span>
              <t t-esc="record.product_id.value"/>
            </span>
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <strong>
            <span class="float-right text-right">
              <t t-esc="record.x_virtual_available.value"/>
            </span>
          </strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </t>
  </div>
</t>

<t t-foreach="record.x_bom_line_ids.raw_value" t-as="room">
  <img t-att-src="kanban_image('mrp.bom.line', 'x_image', room)" t-att-data-member_id="room" />
```

My error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to mention the model of the record you are writing this template for. From your code it is apparent that you are trying to display `value` field for two relational field, one is `product_id`, another one is `x_virtual_available`. The given error message is appearing because, either one of the related field of your record is unset, hence the value being False/empty for python, and `undefined` for javascript. And as you are trying to access value field of that related field, you are getting this error. To solve this error, have a close look to your record and check for those fields value.

```
<t t-name="kanban-box">
  <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_card  {{ record.x_bom_line_ids.raw_value }}">
    <t t-if="record.x_bom_line_ids.raw_value">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <strong>
            <span>
              <t t-esc="record.product_id.name"/>
            </span>
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <strong>
            <span class="float-right text-right">
              <t t-esc="record.x_virtual_available"/>
            </span>
          </strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </t>
  </div>
</t>

<t t-foreach="record.x_bom_line_ids.raw_value" t-as="room">
  <img t-att-src="kanban_image('mrp.bom.line', 'x_image', room)" t-att-data-member_id="room" />
```

Comment: sorry, but I do not understand your answer.
I added an x_virtual_available field in the model: mrp.bom.line and the product_id field is there.

Comment: the x_virtual_available field is of floating type and is linked product_id.virtual_available

and product_id is a many2one related to product.product

Comment: You are trying to get `value` attribute of a `float` field??

Comment: The problem is, suppose you are trying to load the template for `mrp.bom.line` record with id `10`, that record with id 10 has one of this field `x_virtual_available` or `product_id ` not set, so the value is undefined. Moreover, no float field or `product.product` record has this attribute `value`. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: @arryph maybe better formatted code would help to read it ;-)

Comment: @isabellecollinmilliet i think arryph has it correct and `product_id` is missing ('cause floats are filled with 0.0 as default). In a original Odoo kanban view (lead) you can see that Odoo is checking if `value` is set before using it: `<span t-if="record.partner_id.value"> <t t-esc="record.partner_id.value"/></span>`

Comment: @CZoellner hehe yeah my bad, I copied the code from question but somehow indentation got removed. fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I understood the mistake I was focusing on a field many2many instead of one2many!
the problem solved but now I try to do the same thing with another field one2many and it does not work the first part works but not the second why?

```
 <p>
               <t t-foreach="record.x_bomlineids.raw_value"  t-as="r">
                <span style="color:blue !important;">
                <strong> <t t-esc="r.x_name" t-att-data-list_id="r"/></strong></span>
                 <span style="color:grey !important;"> Démixé libre: </span><strong> 
 <t t-esc="r.x_virtual_available" /> </strong><t t-esc="r.x_unite"/>   <br/>


                 </t>
                    </p>
                 <p>
                        <t t-foreach="record.bom_line_ids.raw_value"  t-as="l">
                <span style="color:blue !important;">
                <strong> <t t-esc="l.product_tmpl_id" t-att-data-list_id="l"/> 
 </strong></span>
                <span style="color:grey !important;"> stock coli mixte: </span> 
 <strong><t t-esc="l.x_virtual_available" /> </strong><t t-esc="l.x_unite"/>   <br/>
                       </t>
            </p>
```

Comment: the first part shows the data but the second nothing
if I put "l" alone then I have the id that appears but impossible to access a specific field

Comment: I found the solution for the 2nd part but when I declare it the first part does not show anything anymore

Comment: 1 part:<p>
               <t t-foreach="record.x_bomlineids.raw_value"  t-as="r">
                <span style="color:blue !important;">
                <strong> <t t-esc="r.x_name" t-att-data-list_id="r"/></strong></span>
                 <span style="color:grey !important;"> Démixé libre: </span><strong> 
                <t t-esc="r.x_virtual_available" /> </strong><t t-esc="r.x_unite"/>   <br/>

                 </t>
                    </p>
                     </div>

Comment: second part:     <div class="oe_kanban_content">
                                        <t t-foreach="record.x_composants.raw_value"  t- 
       as="l">
                                       <span style="color:blue !important;">
                                        <strong>Peux se trouver dans: <t t-esc="l.x_names" t- 
        att-data-list_id="r"/></strong></span>
                                       <br/>
                                      </t>
                                     </div>